# Granularity of time in Python

Tags: python, time

In Python shell under Anaconda prompt under Windows 10, the following program:

```
a = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
b = a

n = 0
while b == a:
    b = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    n +=1

print(n, a, b-a)
```

prints sometimes `b-a` around 1ms, and sometimes around 15.61 ms. Why is this?

```
>>> exec(open("stamp.py").read())
602 1562500102.504166 0.015616178512573242
>>> exec(open("stamp.py").read())
640 1562500103.832325 0.015614986419677734
>>> exec(open("stamp.py").read())
788 1562500106.503157 0.0009992122650146484
>>> exec(open("stamp.py").read())
8270 1562500108.457863 0.015616893768310547
>>> exec(open("stamp.py").read())
6245 1562500113.863885 0.015617132186889648
>>> exec(open("stamp.py").read())
9032 1562500116.035434 0.015618085861206055
>>> exec(open("stamp.py").read())
2889 1562500117.547767 0.015616178512573242
>>> exec(open("stamp.py").read())
256 1562500119.647477 0.0010001659393310547
```

Comment: You'd have to check the implementation for MS Windows. Just a hint: One part is the resolution of the time source, the other is that of the scheduler.